# Is there a compact way to encode binary literal data in Java?

Tags: java, binary

I can do this in Java

```
final byte[] b = new byte[]{0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
                            (byte)0x80, 0x40, 0x20, (byte)0xff,
                            (byte)0xef, 0x40, 0x30, (byte)0xfe,
                            0x3f, (byte)0x90, 0x44, 0x78};
```

whereas in Python 2.x I can just use

```
b = '\x01\x02\x04\x08\x80\x40\x20\xff\xef\x40\x30\xfe\x3f\x90\x44\x78'
```

The Java syntax is a pain and needs `(byte)` casts to handle values with most significant bit set.

Is there an easier way? (aside from writing a helper class to turn a string like `"01020408804020ffef4030fe3f904478"`  into a `byte[]`)

Comment: You could use `BigInteger` to avoid having to write the helper class yourself.

Comment: *"aside from writing a helper class..."* I suspect not.

Comment: @malbarbo -- Not a duplicate of that question, which just wants to know how to fix a problem caused by lack of casts. I *know* that the default way to create a byte array literal in Java requires casts, I want to know if there is a way to express byte arrays more compactly.

Comment: This question pre-supposes the answer to the above-linked question; not a dupe in my opinion.  Unfortunately, I think the answer to OP's question (is there a better way) is 'no'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick your poison. All the alternatives are painful in one way or another.
[It is lamentable that Java's `byte` type is signed instead of unsigned](https://www.nayuki.io/page/javas-signed-byte-type-is-a-mistake).

1. Hexadecimal byte constants with casting. For uniformness, you should just cast every element. This is okay for very short lists.

   ```
   byte[] b = {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x7F, (byte)0x80, (byte)0xFF};
   ```
2. Signed decimal byte constants, to avoid casting. Very few tools can read or write this format easily though. Probably not useful in practice.

   ```
   byte[] b = {0, 127, -128, -1};
   ```
3. Int-to-byte conversion via a helper function. It does look neat and tidy, and is helpful for medium amounts of data.

   ```
   byte[] b = toBytes(new int[]{0x00, 0x7F, 0x80, 0xFF});

   static byte[] toBytes(int[] x) {
       byte[] y = new byte[x.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
           y[i] = (byte)x[i];
       return y;
   }
   ```
4. String-to-byte conversion. Now you can use just 2 characters per byte (no commas or `0x`), plus a constant amount of overhead.

   ```
   byte[] b = hexToBytes("007F80FF");

   static byte[] hexToBytes(String s) {
       byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
       for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
           b[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
       return b;
   }
   ```
5. Base64-encoded string. This is even more compact than #4, but requires work to encode. Decoding is easy using [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) (Java SE 8+). I have one actual example where I [stored a Base64 binary blob in my Java source code](https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/blob/master/java/io/nayuki/qrcodegen/QrSegmentAdvanced.java).